# Set size of WordPress thumbnail post

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I create function to get post thumbnail  by category ID.
this is the code:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <?php
        foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $single_post) 
        {
            $single_post_ID = $single_post->ID;
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($single_post_ID, 'medium') );
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
        <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $single_post_ID ); ?></h2>
                <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Commander</a> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Plus Info</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I want set the size of the thumb to 800px by 500px with wordpress functions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what i'm seeign, your WordPress function outputs your image inside .thumbnail. so do something this

```
 .thumbnail {
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 overflow: hidden; /* Cuts off whatever goes beyond the given width */
}


 .thumbnail img {
  width: 100%; /* 100% equals 800px as defined for .thumbnail */
  height: auto; /* Allows the image a breathing option so it doesn't deteriorate */
}
```

**Note:** The containing element already has a given width(800px)  so the image won't go beyond 800px

Comment: It's not done with a Wordpress function like asked. It's a nice solution if you want to use width 100% on image with a responsive container, etc. But if the design is static, why should the image be bigger then it need?

Comment: The containing element already has a given width so the image won't go beyond 800px

Comment: Yes, it will work but the real image will be loaded and it will be bigger then needed. It is useful to have it bigger when it is responsive but if not, make multiple image sizes to keep you page load lighter. Imagine have 100 + thumbnails with image that are too big for nothing...

Comment: the same note of @AnnieCaron

Comment: @AnnieCaron whatever overflows won't show. Just optimize your images.

Comment: @Sleek Geek I know it won't show but optimizing images = right size for your needs, cache, gzip and compressing with lossless compressing algorithm, etc.

Comment: Page load speed, gzip and cache are different topics and can be approached differently.

Comment: Yes, I was only pointing the fact that the right images sizes for your need is a part of it! As stated here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages "image format capabilities, quality settings, resolution, and more" Crunching images with CSS still load the full image behind. Not nice for my phone dataplan for example :P just pointing the right way to think: use what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use add_image_size in you functions.php: [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

```
add_image_size('my-thumbnail', 800, 500, true);
```

Or use a plugin to create more image size like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/).

Then change the medium format to your new format. It will be better then a bigger image set to a smaller in CSS (performance issue). After that, always depends if your website is responsive or not for the use of a bigger image but that is another topic.

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($single_post_ID, 'my-thumbnail') );
```

**Update:** Images must be reupload or use this plugin: [Resize Image After Upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/resize-image-after-upload/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you must reupload your files OR use this plugin to do it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/resize-image-after-upload/

Comment: Read the plugin description, it is a nice comment about the whole image thing! It also compress the images.